# Regex : I need to extract all words except the string `ignore`

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Take this as an example

```
hello-world
ignore-good-morning-ignore
good-night-ignore
```

I tried negative look ahead and negative look behinds

```
^(?<!ignore)\S+(?!ignore)$
```

But it seems to pick the whole 3 words

Expected result

```
hello-world
good-morning
good-night
```

Actual result

```
hello-world
ignore-good-morning-ignore
good-night-ignore
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to swap the logic and actually match the word you'd like to ignore and replace those values leaving the string in the expected output. For example:

```
(?<=\S)-ignore\b|\bignore-(?=\S)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MQZDOn/1). You can see the results in the bottom of the screen when we replace matched substring with nothing.

---

- `(?<=\S)` - Postive lookbehind to assert position is preceded by a non-whitespace character.
- `-ignore\b` - Match '-ignore' followed by a word-boundary.
- `|` - Or:
- `\bignore-` - Match a word-boundary followed by 'ignore-'.
- `(?=\S)` - Positive lookahead to assert position is followed by a non-whitespace character.

Note, if your string can also just be 'ignore' without anything else, you could just add to the alternation to capture that too.

Comment: This is correct answer and should be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex, there is only one way to match everything except a
certain string.

Of course, splitting on the word or phrase to create a list of segments is a sure fire way to accomplish this task,
there may be benefits to matching the specific segments withing the text string instead.

On thing is you'd get a match location without having to do a lot of string length
arithmetic if you were to use something like split.

For regular expressions, the only way is to use an engine that can "skip" words or phrases.
The only class of engines that can do that are the ***Perl, PCRE, or Python "regex"***  ones.

In fact, they invented a construct that can skip a word or phrase after you match it.
This is the   *(*SKIP)* construct.

The preliminary check contains the skip and since this is an example using
PCRE, I just reused some of the code as a functon call  *"(?1)"* to check that
there is no words ahead as the stream is traversed.

If you can't use the Perl / PCRE style engines, you would be better off using
your favorite split function.

```
((?:-|\b)ignore(?:-|\b))(*SKIP)(?!)|(?:(?!(?1)).)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/Wy21OZ/1

```
   (                             # (1 start)
      (?: - | \b )
      ignore
      (?: - | \b )
   )                             # (1 end)
   (*SKIP)(?!)
 | 
   (?: 
     (?! (?1) ) .
   )+
```

Comment: I've never seen this syntax before, interesting answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture multiple occurrences of varying amount, try this version without the mark of the start `^` and end `$` of string (so that we can catch everything):

```
(?!\bignore\b)\b(\w+)\b
```

[image]

Where:

- `(?!\bignore\b)` - Negative look ahead to assert that the string that we will capture is not exactly the word "ignore".
- `\b` - Make sure that the word that we would capture is the whole word, and not a partial e.g. "gnore"
- `(\w+)` - Capture the words
- `\b` - As above, make sure we would capture the whole word

Comment: If you don't mind me nitpick one small issue is that this would also skip over word like `ignorethis`. Maybe a word-boundary in the lookahead solves it.

Comment: Great find!! Yes, I haven't taken that into account. I updated the lookahead to make sure that the word is strictly "ignore". Many thanks @JvdV :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use C#, you could split string and skip `ignore` entries:

```cs
var words = new[]
{
  "hello-world",
  "ignore-good-morning-ignore",
  "good-night-ignore",
  "good-ignore-night",
};
foreach (var word in words)
{
  var word2 = string.Join("-", word.Split("-").Where(w => w != "ignore"));
  Console.WriteLine(word2);
}
/*
    Output:
      hello-world
      good-morning
      good-night
      good-night
*/
```